# What's special about deflateInit2 that prevents deflateSetHeader be used with deflateInit?

Tags: zlib, api-design

I'm trying to learn how to use zlib functions in my C language project. I need to support both RFC-1950 zlib format as well as RFC-1952 gzip format in my application.

To use gzip format, the `deflateSetHeader` must be used. But while reading the documentation from the [zlib source](http://zlib.net), it appears to say that `deflateSetHeader` must be used with `deflateInit2` rather than `deflateInit`. But the reason for this is not explained.

**Q**: Can `deflateSetHeader` be used with `deflateInit`? Or why does it has to be used with `deflateInit2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need to use `deflateSetHeader()` in order to produce the gzip format. You just need to use `deflateInit2()` and request the gzip format with the `windowBits` parameter value. The use of `deflateSetHeader()` is entirely optional, and is used only when you want the gzip header contents to be different from the default header.

Yes, you can only use `deflateSetHeader()` after `deflateInit2()`, because `deflateSetHeader()` only applies to the gzip header, and the only way to request the gzip format in the first place is to use `deflateInit2()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's all mentioned in http://zlib.net/manual.html#Advanced

zlib can be requested to produce gzip data by setting window-size to a value greater than 15. This value can only be set with `deflateInit2` and not `deflateInit`

Likewise, values less than 0 can be used to request raw "unwrapped" deflate data.